# Getting Room Data in Settings Activity

Tags: android, settings, android-room

I am looking to get the email from a user of the app and compare it against my Room database.

My Room follows the Dao->Database->Repository->ViewModel pattern.

I am working in the GeneralPreferenceFragment and I have put in an EditTextPreference.

Should I use the ViewModelProviders.of(...) or should I just create an instance of the repository? I have tried to use the ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class) but it doesn't compile. Is there something special I need to do for the SettingActivity?

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("user_email_address"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("user_password"));

        Preference email = findPreference("user_email_address");
            if (email == null){

            } else {
                checkEmailAgainstDatabase(email);

            }

    }

    private void checkEmailAgainstDatabase(Preference email) {

        String getEmail = email.toString();
        //Get a call to the database
```